# How to run a background service when the application is closed using WorkManager?

Tags: java, android

Previously I tried to run background services using WorkManager, the requests I used were OneTimeWorkRequest and PeriodicWorkRequest.

When I tried PeriodicWorkRequest there was an oddity, the oddity was when I closed the application, the service stopped, but when I reopened the application, the service returned.

```
Constraints.Builder constraint = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED);

Data.Builder data = new Data.Builder();
data.putString("url", "https://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4");

WorkRequest request = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(BackgroundDownloadService.class, 12,
            TimeUnit.HOURS)
            .setInputData(data.build())
            .setConstraints(constraint.build())
            .build();

WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(request);
```

BackgroundDownloadService.java:

```
public class BackgroundDownloadService extends Worker {
    private Context context;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    @Override
    public WorkerResult doWork() {
        context = getApplicationContext();
        Data data = getInputData();
        String url = "";
        if(data != null) {
            url = data.getString("url", "");
        }
        String mainName = "renaldi";
        String mimeType = url.substring(url.length()-4);
        String namePath = mainName + "Files-"+changeFormat(new Date())+mimeType;

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        createNotification();

        AndroidNetworking.initialize(context);

        AndroidNetworking.download(url, context.getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/video/"  , namePath)
                .setTag("download")
                .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
                .build()
                .setDownloadProgressListener(new DownloadProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(long bytesDownloaded, long totalBytes) {
                        final int dl_progress = (int) ((bytesDownloaded * 100l) / totalBytes);
                        updateNotification(dl_progress);
                    }
                })
                .startDownload(new DownloadListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDownloadComplete() {
                        onDownloadCompleted();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError error) {
                    }
                });

        return WorkerResult.SUCCESS;
    }

    public String changeFormat(Date date) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmssSSS");
        String dateFormat = format.format(date);
        return dateFormat;
    }

    private void updateNotification(int currentProgress) {
        notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, currentProgress, false);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText("Downloaded: " + currentProgress + "%");
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    private void onDownloadCompleted() {
        notificationManager.cancel(0);
        notificationBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText("Video Download Complete");
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

    }

    private void createNotification() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("id", "an", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);

            notificationChannel.setDescription("no sound");
            notificationChannel.setSound(null, null);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(false);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(false);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "id")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
                .setContentTitle("Download")
                .setContentText("Downloading Video")
                .setDefaults(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Are you giving me a solution to run a background service when the application is closed using workmanager ??

Comment: you cannot reliably start background service unless the application is in the foreground

Comment: Have you tried starting the service in a worker with the context of worker?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari What do you mean bro?

Comment: Can you add code for BackgroundDownloadService class?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari Ok, I will add it in this thread.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Can WorkManager run foreground services?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari I've added the code for BackgroundDownloadService.java

Answer (score 0):

According to the Worker API documentation:

> This method (doWork() of Worker class) is for **synchronous** processing of your work, meaning that
>   once you return from that method, the Worker is considered to be
>   finished and will be **destroyed**. If you need to do your work
>   **asynchronously** or **call asynchronous** APIs, you should use
>   **ListenableWorker**.

So consider extending `ListenableWorker` instead of `Worker` and see how it works.